# Retrieving custom CMS field from Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom "Meta title" field in Magento for CMS pages. The field displays on the admin and saves to the db, but I'm having trouble retrieving this information. I'm using the model/observer method.

Observer class

```
public function cmsField($observer)
{

    // $model = Mage::registry('cms_page');

    $form = $observer->getEvent()->getForm();

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('example_metainfo_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('cms')->__('Meta Info'),'class'=>'fieldset-wide'));
    //add new field
    $fieldset->addField('metatitle', 'text', array(
        'name'      => 'metatitle',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Metatitle'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Metatitle'),
        'disabled'  => false,
        //set field value
        // 'value'     => $model->getMetatitle()
    ));

    $form->setValues(Mage::registry('cms_page')->getData());
}
```

do I need to add some other method to retrieve this value then? Or what is the best/most efficient way to display this information on the frontend? I've tried various approaches, but none have worked so far.